# Negative response time in Jetty server access log

Tags: jetty

I'm running on Jetty and my access log is configured to show the response time.

today I noticed that a very minimal amount of the requests (about 30 out of 600K) have a negative response time and I was wondering if anyone ever encountered such a behavior.

This is a sample of my response:
<[IP]> -  -  <[date]> "POST <[url]> HTTP/1.0" 201 461  -18096

In case you want to identify this in the access log - this is the grep command i used:

grep --color "-[0-9][0-9]*" server-access.2013_12_09.log

**Jetty Version:** 8.1.8

**Setup in jetty.xml:**

```
<New id="request-log-handler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
<Set name="requestLog">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
    <Arg>
      <Property name="logging.httpAccessLog" default="logs/app-access.yyyy_mm_dd.log" />
    </Arg>
    <Set name="retainDays">
      <Property name="logging.accessLogRetentionInDays" default="10" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="append">
      <Property name="logging.httpAccessLogAppend" default="true" />
    </Set>
    <!-- logs referer and user agent -->
    <Set name="extended">
      <Property name="logging.httpAccessLogExtended" default="false" />
    </Set>
    <!-- response time -->
    <Set name="logLatency">
      <Property name="logging.httpAccessLogLatency" default="true" />
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

Comment: What version of Jetty? (be specific), and include how you have access logging configured in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jetty 9.1.0.

Key:

- `<name>` = optional / configurable entry on line
- `{name}` = mandatory entry

`<servername> {X-Forwarded-For||remote-addr} - {authentication/principal/name} [{request-timestamp}] "{method} {uri} {protocol}" {response-status-code} {response-content-length} <extended-log> <cookies> <latency>`

Where:

- `<servername>` can be the request/Host header
- `<extended-log>` can be [`"{referer} {user-agent}"`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L228-L246)
- `<cookies>` can be [`" -"`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L177-L178) or [`"{cookie.name}={cookie-value};"`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L181-L190)
- `<latency>` can be [`(now - request.getTimeStamp())`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L200-L201)

Interestingly, it appears that your system clock adjusted during a request.  A full 18 seconds!

Here's why this is the leading theory ...

The [request.timestamp is set when the request starts](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel.java#L482-L483), then the [latency is computed later during the access/request logging](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.1.0.v20131115/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L198-L202).  For there to be a negative value, either something outside of Jetty itself reset the request.timeout, or the system clock changed.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable explanation because: 1. I see that all the negative numbers appear in the same time 'chunks'; 2. I have 2 machines running my servers and in one machine the negative values are around 5 seconds and on the other they are all around 18 seconds