# Why latency of requests to Jetty on EC2 Linux high?

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, jetty, latency, jetty-9

I'm running `jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612` on `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)` over AWS EC2 `m1.small` Linux machine.

It communicates with mobile apps with a mean count of 36 hits per minute, about 60% of traffic using HTTP/2.0, mean CPU utilisation is ~15% at peak and network i/o stands around 5 MB per minute, so it doesn't have any resource choking due to traffic.

Jetty's `AsyncNCSARequestLog` latency logging shows an average latency of around 2000 ms. As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477966/negative-response-time-in-jetty-server-access-log), latency is calculated `(now - request.getTimeStamp())`, so it does not separate the time it took Jetty to handle the request between the time it took to create the HTTP connection.

How do I analyse the request's latency in order to find the bottle neck?

Comment: Be precise.  What *specific version* of Jetty and Java are you using?

Comment: `jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612` and `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)`